# Python Selenium Reference Error in browser

Tags: python, reference, selenium-chromedriver

-I am trying to scrape the following website:
url='https://www.justdial.com/Delhi/Screen-Printers/nct-10423785'
-I am trying to iterate and extract all the cities from this HTML block which has similar elements for each city
 **Screen Printers in Delhi** ,
-then click on the city go the page get similar vendor web elements

** Vardhman Ad Print  
**
then clicking  each and extracting details like name ,address,etc
'''

```
for city in cities:
    city=wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(('xpath', '//a[@class="jsx-ab98041208827c27 anchor"]')))
    print(city.text)
    time.sleep(2)
    city.click()
    screen_printers=WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(('xpath','//a[@class="jsx-4d407376001b01ad resultbox_title_anchor font22 fw500 color111 line_clamp_1"]')))
    for printer in screen_printers:
        printer=WebDriverWait(driver, 30)(EC.visibility_of_element_located(('xpath','//a[@class="jsx-4d407376001b01ad resultbox_title_anchor font22 fw500 color111 line_clamp_1"]')))
```

print(printer.text)

'''
**While I run this code I'm getting the following error in the browser:**
An error occurred while processing your request.
Reference #97.6e87d317.1693396043.3d30f11.
and also
-I'm getting time a timeout exception
-Mentioned below are the details of the exception

-

```
**TimeoutException      Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[34], line 39
     37 time.sleep(2)
     38 city.click()
---> 39 screen_printers=WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located(('xpath','//a[@class="jsx-4d407376001b01ad resultbox_title_anchor font22 fw500 color111 line_clamp_1"]')))
     40 for printer in screen_printers:
     41     printer=WebDriverWait(driver, 30)(EC.visibility_of_element_located(('xpath','//a[@class="jsx-4d407376001b01ad resultbox_title_anchor font22 fw500 color111 line_clamp_1"]')))
```

**
-I tried a lot to resolve this error not sure how can i solve this
-Please help me solve this